# Surround Sound and Video Setup

Tags: sound, video, pulseaudio, mythtv

Ok. We're trying (really hard) to port from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu to be exact)

Problem is... I just doesn't work as good as a Windows Box... The box is to function as a media centre and all reviews seen, just does not match up (unless those guys never used Windows ever)

The box consists of:-

1. Intel Dual Core LGA 775 3.2Ghz Proc
2. Kingston 4GB DDR-3 Memory
3. Seagate 1TB SATA-2 HDD
4. ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM Motherboard
5. nVidia Corporation GT216 [GeForce GT 220]

OS : Ubuntu 10.10 x64 Desktop

The propriety driver for the GT220 was installed.
Ubuntu Restricted Media Formats were installed.

Software in Question:-

1. MythTV and
2. Movie Player

Problems is:

1. Video is choppy... er .. horizontal "lines" can be seen within the parts of the screen that has the most movement.
2. Only Stereo Sound can be obtained from a 5.1 Surround Setup
3. Three weeks later... and I'm tired with this setup... therefore this posting is my final attempt prior to moving back to Windows

Some Debug info:-

## lspci -v

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 836d
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: intel-agp

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
Memory behind bridge: fd000000-fe9fffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000de000000-00000000efffffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8445
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
Memory at fcffc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
Memory behind bridge: 80000000-801fffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080200000-00000000803fffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
Memory behind bridge: fea00000-feafffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080400000-00000000805fffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM,P5LD2-VM Mainboard
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
I/O ports at c480 [size=32]
Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM,P5LD2-VM Mainboard
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
I/O ports at c800 [size=32]
Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM,P5LD2-VM Mainboard
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
I/O ports at c880 [size=32]
Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM,P5LD2-VM Mainboard
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
I/O ports at cc00 [size=32]
Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM,P5LD2-VM Mainboard
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
Memory at fcffbc00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=32
Memory behind bridge: feb00000-febfffff
Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM Motherboard
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: leds-ss4200, iTCO_wdt, intel-rng

00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 8f [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM Motherboard
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
I/O ports at b800 [size=8]
I/O ports at b480 [size=4]
I/O ports at 08f0 [size=8]
I/O ports at 08f8 [size=4]
I/O ports at b000 [size=16]
Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA IDE Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 8f [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM Motherboard
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
I/O ports at c400 [size=8]
I/O ports at c080 [size=4]
I/O ports at c000 [size=8]
I/O ports at bc00 [size=4]
I/O ports at b880 [size=16]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT216 [GeForce GT 220] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: nVidia Corporation Device 0715
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at fd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at de000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at dc00 [size=128]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at fe900000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidia-current, nouveau, nvidiafb

01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
Subsystem: nVidia Corporation Device 0715
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at fe9fc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83fe
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
Memory at feac0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
I/O ports at ec00 [size=128]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: atl1c
Kernel modules: atl1c

04:01.0 Multimedia controller: Philips Semiconductors SAA7131/SAA7133/SAA7135 Video Broadcast Decoder (rev d0)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P7131 Dual
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
Memory at febff800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: saa7134
Kernel modules: saa7134
```

## aplay -L

```
default
pulse
Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC887 Analog
Front speakers
surround40:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC887 Analog
4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC887 Analog
4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC887 Analog
5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC887 Analog
5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC887 Analog
7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC887 Digital
IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC887 Analog
Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
HDA Intel, ALC887 Digital
Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC887 Analog
Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
HDA Intel, ALC887 Digital
Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC887 Analog
Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
HDA Intel, ALC887 Digital
Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC887 Analog
Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
HDA Intel, ALC887 Digital
Hardware device with all software conversions
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
HDA NVidia, NVIDIA HDMI
Hardware device with all software conversions
tv@tv-System-Product-Name:~$
```

`pavucontrol` 
only provides "Analogue Stereo Ouput" as an option on the "Internal Audio" device, which is the only functional option.

`speaker-test -c 6 -Dplug:surround51 -t wav`
provides only the "lady's voice" on the Front Left and Front Right Speakers.

What bugs me the most, is that one just cannot find any proper solution to the sound issue. In addition, would someone be as kind as clearing the usage / dependency / requirements of "ALSA" and "PULSEAUDIO" ? Does one still need ALSA with PULSEAUDIO ?

And for the life of me, I cannot find a working "Mixer Console" for PULSEAUDIO (Therefore the query above) ALSAMIXER nor KMIX works?

Will there be help or should I switch back to Microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be a little bit angry and I don't blame you. The migration from a Microsoft based system to the freedom can be a little bit irritating.

First of all, I can't give a suggestion for a really complex situation like that you are facing which seems to be a lot of work to be done and you may feel disappointed.

My suggestion for you: Give a chance to a distribution with pre-loaded software, in which you may perform several tests and find a way to learn how the things works inside of an Ubuntu system.

There are several pre-loaded systems that you can find in Distrowatch, of which I strongly suggest you the ***[Israel Remix Team](http://israelremixteam.freeforums.org/index.php)*** distro, in which you will find the support from the creator of this distro who is a very experienced man in which refers to Linux systems.

There are several distributions ready for multi-media (audio, graphics and video), office, programming and several other tasks.

Run a live session, from which you can check the pre-installed programs and their behavior on your system.

With the usage of these pre-installed distributions you may learn the way you did in your pre-installed Window$. Unless you started learning to make and program your windows from scratch, which I doubt a lot.

BTW: Israel Remix Team is pre-loaded with lots of software for the multi-media (audio, images and video creation/edition), programming tools, apache server, php, TV Players, Media players, and lots of useful stuff.

You may wish to check also the [***Ubuntu Studio***](http://ubuntustudio.org/) distro, which is designed mostly for the multi-media purposes (audio, images and video creation/edition).

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured your sound card to run in 5.1 mode in the Sound Preferences control panel?  You should be able to configure this from the Hardware tab:

[image]

By default this would probably be set to stereo, since many cards support multiple speaker configurations without a good way of telling the OS what configuration has been plugged in.

After setting the hardware profile, you can easily test it from within this control panel.  With this change, you should find that stereo output is sent to both front and rear speakers in addition to supporting surround sound output.

Comment: I use Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS and I don't have the "Sound Preferences" panel you're talking about. Why? or Where is it?